# Top Bar In View Controller Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I set I created a custom UI colour and then created a white status bar programatically. Next, I wanted to create a top bar. I clicked on the view controller, went over the attributes inspector, and selected: "top bar- Translucent Black Navigation Bar with prompt". However, when I ran it, it didn't show up at all! How can I make it show up? And also, how can I have a title in the centre of it?

Note: this is the initial view controller
Note: I'm using swift 2.0

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a UINavigationController to the ViewController.

For that:

1.Select your ViewController.

2.Just go to Editor in Xcode and then Embed In-->Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow as below image**

[image]

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: what about the bottom bar? thats not showing up either (translucent black tab bar)

Answer (score 0):

Yo should embed your ViewController in UINavigationController.

- Select your ViewController in the Interface Builder
- Go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Comment: how would I add a title in it?

Comment: self.title = "Your Title"

Comment: Okay I followed what you said. However, I had a white status bar before which I added programmatically and i changed the value of it in the plist file. This changed to black and the top bar will only be white after using your changes

Comment: any way to change font size of the title?

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)]